# Is there a flag in Python 3 that reports if a cast is not required

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm converting a rather large Python project from Python 2.7 to Python 3.x.  I am having to change the output types of functions.  In the past I might cast to str() or unicode() when using a returned value.  In some cases I may no longer need to cast the returned value.  Is there a flag that would print out something like 'unnecessary cast on line x for str().'

Hoping that such a flag would work for ALL unnecessary casts.

Comment: No. There is no such flag.

Comment: For debugging purposes you could override the `str` and `unicode` functions to check the type of the input first and print a debug statement if the input is already `str` or `unicode`. This in general sounds like an application for [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/), but unless the code is already written for it, it would be a big re-write.

Comment: TY!  There are quite a few flags such as --b and -3 to help with conversion to Python 3 but they don't cover this situation. Also, it isn't just strings I was hoping for help with but ANY unnecessary cast. Maybe some of the Python programmers would pick this up.

Comment: I think searching for such strings is the best way. On the other hand, with such constructors (not cast), the code check the type and do nothing if it is already a string, so you would not get much performance penality. Usually on old code, there are many better ways to improve performance.